# Python saves empty html file

Tags: python, html, python-requests

```
import requests
url = 'https://hkpropel.humankinetics.com/mylibrary.htm'
r = requests.get(url)

with open('saving.html', 'wb+') as f:
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

I'm trying to save web in html file, it's work fine for others web , but for this one it's always save empty data

Comment: Works for me. The HTML is written to the file, but the page is blank when I open it. There was quite a few blank lines at the top of the savings.html file but otherwise the content is there. Note, when you use with open, you don't have to close the file.

Comment: This site request login, so you have to authenticate first to next get this page

Comment: Ah, I see now that the content written to the file is only JS and CSS. Nothing is rendered in the browser.

Comment: shall I use Selenium at first, and then save in html?

Answer (score 0):

The page you're trying to copy likely requires you to be logged in. If your not it redirects you to the login page and you ended up getting a copy of that.

Also, I'm pretty new to Python, but I don't think you need to use `f.close()`